# How do I hide navigation header from navigation experimental in react native only from certain pages?

Tags: navigation, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to hide the navigation header only from certain pages in my react native application. But I am not getting the solution for it. I don't want to use different navigation experimental for those pages.

```
   class AppContainerWithCardStack extends React.Component {
     render() {
         let { navigationState, backAction } = this.props

         return (

          <NavigationCardStack
            navigationState={navigationState}
            onNavigateBack={backAction}
            style={styles.container}
            direction='vertical' 

            renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            renderScene={this._renderScene}
        />
         )
      }
  _renderHeader(props)
  { const route = props.scene.route
    if (route.key === 'Splash') 
    return null
    else
    return <NavigationHeader
                    {...props}
                    onNavigateBack={props.scene.index > 1 ? backAction : undefined}
                    renderTitleComponent={props => {
                        const title = props.scene.route.title
                        return <NavigationHeader.Title>{title}</NavigationHeader.Title>
                    }}/>

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We hide navigation header in our Intro first screen with this code (reduced for readability):

```jsx
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native'
const { CardStack, Header } = NavigationExperimental

class IntroContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return <CardStack
            navigationState={this.props.nav}
            renderScene={this.renderScene}
            renderHeader={this.renderHeader}/>
    }
    renderHeader(sceneProps) {
        const route = sceneProps.scene.route
        if (route.key == 'Splash') return null // Here we skip header on Splash screen
        // Next, we remove back navigation on second screen (optional)
        const onNavigateBack = sceneProps.scene.index > 1 ? this.navigateBack : undefined
        return <Header {...sceneProps} onNavigateBack={onNavigateBack}/>
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked.. I used renderOverlay property in place of renderHeader in my code. Thanks @vovkasm

Comment: I have removed the header from splash using the same code. But the animation is coming when second page header is loading with the first page header title(which i removed from above code). How this is happening? please tell me how do I remove that? @vovkasm